# Bootstrap - forcing alignment of responsive elements

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I've got a couple of elements that I'm really struggling to align horizontally. I've got a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/IPWright83/rNurL/) to try and illustrate it. The layout that I'm trying to achieve in particular is looking at the first/left most Email field.

I wish to have both the slider and input field aligned with the label if space, or both of them sitting below the label otherwise.

[image]

What I find however is that I end up with the controls wrapping, or large amounts of whitespace (or greyspace even) around the textbox - rather than it filling to take up the space.

Unfortunately I've found that I can't seem to use `col` classes on the toggle because this causes issues with the rendering of it.

**EDIT**

So I've tried using a bootstrap library for my sliders instead in the hope that it'll allow for a better layout, and attempted to use bootstrap column sizing. This leaves me with the similar problems as you can see in the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/IPWright83/RXTGq/).

I would still **prefer** to use the first library if I can so bonus if I can solve the problem with the first library.

My HTML looks something like this:

```
<div id="settingsBar" class="">
    <div class="well bs-component col-sm-6">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <fieldset>
                <legend style="color: #ccc;">General</legend>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="txtBackColor" class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-4 control-label">Background Colour</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-8 row">
                        <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-0"></div>
                        <input id="tglBackColor" type="checkbox" name="tglBackColor" class="bootstrap-toggle form-control" checked data-on-color="success" data-off-color="danger">
                        <input id="txtBackColor" type="text" class="colorPicker form-control col-xs-10 col-sm-7 col-md-10 col-lg-11" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem I have is that depending on the size, the boxes overlap. What I want is for the final colour box to shrink down to fit on the same line, and the label sits either above or inline if there's enough space.

[image]

Comment: You put cols within rows, don't include the row in the div with the other col's e.g <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-8 row"> - put a <div class="row"> around that that and remove the row so it becomes: <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-8">

Comment: @RyanMcDonough: OK - taking that out doesn't seem to make a different though I don't believe? If it does and fixes things can you modify the JSFiddle to illustrate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bootstrap has col- controls for different sizes.**

You can control rendering of collumns by using proper classes, e.g.:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"></div>
```

This means, collumn with such class will render over responsivity like 100% of container width (smartphones), 50% of container width (tablets), 33% of container width(small notebook/desktop screens) and 25% of container widht on high resolution displays.

You can also try put div with class="row" before your columns. **Class row will cancel left and right padding of collumns. E.g.:**

```
<div class="row">   
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">some div</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">some div</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">some div</div>
</div>
```

You can find more info about bootstrap basics [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)

Comment: Hi Ernest - thanks for your answer. Unfortunately as I mentioned these seem to cause issue with the slider that I'm using.

Comment: Hi Ernest - I've actually updated my question and tried to do something along the lines you've said but I still seem to have some issues.

Comment: Hello Ian, it is all about the math. Lets call those divs A(text) B(switcher) C(input). You have them in container, call it X.  No matter what is size of container, on desktop/notebook you need to have ABC 33% of X width. For the phones/tablets you need probably ABC 100% of X width. But this stands only for collumns. And for this is my code above. So, now we have 3 good collumns which works fine so problem is content of those collumns. You need to set-up width of child elements to 100%, instead of using absolute px definitions.  If u will have problems with it, let me know :)

Comment: Enrest - could you try updating the JSFiddle to illustrate for me? I understand the idea of adding up to 12 and trying not to put widths on elements directly...

Comment: That's not bad - but the colour picker still wraps prematurely (plenty of space left and right if it were to remain on the same line) and it doesn't expand as the area grows.

Comment: Man, it is about CSS basics :) http://jsfiddle.net/sawyer/RXTGq/4/  .... I can code it for you if you provide me with image for every breakpoint :) But really, you can control width by changing col- classes if you are not friendly with CSS.

Comment: Thanks Ernest - I guess that where I was getting confused. I thought the CSS col classes were correct (I've spent a couple of hours  fighting with them) - obviously in this case that stray auto width :/ Thanks for your explanations - going to compare to my original to try and learn some for the future.

Comment: You are welcome :) In case you will need any further help, feel free to contact me here or via mail ernest.sawyer[at]detroit.sk :) I will try to help you with better understanding of bootstrap.